# Unable to add file or folder to svn:ignore

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have some files and folders that i am unable to add to ignore because the option is disabled. Why is this so?

[image]

Comment: You should at least mention what program your question is about.

Comment: This does not look like an svn problem (You don't call the `svn` binary), but a problem of [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) or [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Comment: There are so~ many duplicates about this issue. With Eclipse, Netbeans and whatever..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the folder is already under version control.

Here's how I fix this type of problem when it comes up:

1. In your local shell, make a copy of the `.settings` folder
2. Bring up the "SVN Repositories" view in Eclipse
3. Navigate to within the project on the server (*e.g.* `/trunk/cboon/Project1/`)
4. Right-click the `.settings` directory there and delete it
5. Now locally, update the project.  If it feels that `.settings` is in conflict, accept the incoming change.
6. Copy your local back-up of `.settings` back into place and refresh.  It should now have a '?' badge, indicating that it's not under control
7. *Now* you can `svn:ignore` it

Comment: Actually it's not needed to remove the files on the remote repository. You can also do the change locally and commit it.

Comment: It works like charm..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the file has already been added to the ignore list (*svn:ignore*), has also been added to the repository, and now contains some changes. The ignore list is only used for *unversioned files*. However, if the file is already in the repository, it has no effect.

Solve the problem by removing the file from the repository, without removing it from your working copy, e.g. `svn rm --keep-local .settings`.

Answer (score 2):

"You can use svn:ignore property only for unversioned resources, if resource is versioned then "Add to svn:ignore" menu is disabled. In order to add resource to ignored, select unversioned resource which you want to ignore, right click and call Team/Add to svn:ignore, then select ignore method."

Taken from discussion [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/subversive-defects/msg00033.html).